# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'nipy_spectral'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am dealing with error

> "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'nipy_spectral'"

while running silhouette analysis.

The original code was taken from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html). I have added the line that shows the error:

```
color = cm.nipy_spectral(float(i) / n_clusters)
```

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the code with a stack trace from your machine? Maybe there could be some typo or you are assigning `cm` to some other array? you can do `print(type(cm))` just before that line.

Comment: I have added the snippet as an answer to this topic. Hopefully this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you were assigning `cm` to some other array. Correct way is not to assign `cm` to any other array or change the code to

```
matplotlib.cm.nipy_spectral(float(i) / n_clusters)
```

Change it at all the places where `cm` is used.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the snippet of the input data and the result of running print(type(cm)).
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRkTX.png)

Comment: Here is the mistake. As per this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html), cm is `import matplotlib.cm as cm` and not numpy.ndarray. so you should check whether you are assigning `cm` to any array at any place, then change it. Or you could do `matplotlib.cm.nipy_spectral(float(i) / n_clusters)`

Comment: I would not have come to that. Super-super big thanks - IT WORKS NOW !

Comment: Answers are for answers, not comments or posting code. Code should be added to your original question by editing your question.